# Set root password AMI linux

Tags: sudo, password, root, su

I need to set a password for root on EC2 AMI Linux. I have tried with `passwd root` but if I log in with `ec2-user` and run `sudo su`, I get a root bash without asking for a password.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo su` asks for the user's password, the user has to be in the sudo/adm/admin/wheel group (depening on flavour of the OS) to be able to execute `sudo`.

The root password will be prompted when using `su` alone.

Check the settings in `/etc/sudoers` file to see why you are not being asked for a password while using `sudo`. Most likely the time-out is set to a few minutes, allowing you a passwordless sudo for e.g. 15 minutes after a successful password entry.